# nltk 'module' object is not callable in MAC OS

Tags: nltk

I can not call the function in nltk but I'm sure that I've already installed nltk in python as the following pictures

[image]

then I test where is my nltk it shows that

[image]

I don't know what should I do,

Comment: `nltk.tokenize` is a module; the function you want is called `nltk.word_tokenize()`. But please use text, not images. See the site's help section for how to ask questions.

Comment: I tried it told me module object has no attribute path

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `import nltk` imports the nltk module, but the `nltk` module itself contains many other modules. From your example, it seems you are trying to access the function `word_tokenize` from the module `nltk.tokenize`. Thus, you need to call the function:`nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize`. In your case, `nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize("I'm handsome")`.

Alternatively, you can use `from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize` to directly import the `word_tokenize` function, although I would advocate for the former use case since it makes it clear where the function comes from.

You can find information on the other modules, and what functions are available [on the nltk/api website](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html).